# How to generate a website preview?

Tags: jquery

[image]

I would like to implement a similar function just like the Google . But the display of the website preview is slightly different. That means  i would like the preview is show when my cursor is on the link (but not when i press a button),

Are there any j query plugin available for me to implement something like this , thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the [qTip Dynamic website thumbnails](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#websnapr).

Comment: Thanks. Is it a screenshot or actually is a html page?

Comment: what if this site close, so i can not see my preview anymore?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to take the screenshot on the server side. I am not sure how you would do it using javascript, though browser extensions and plugins seem to be able to do it:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ - look into wkhtmltoimage

Comment: Thanks .Not a photo but a website, is it ok? becasue the website is expected to change quite often